# What are the most respectable Bitcoin news websites?

Tags: websites, news-coverage

Which blogs or websites are the most respected in the community to bring everyone up-to-date with the Bitcoin-related news? I'm not talking about the forums, as the sheer volume of messages are overwhelming, nor am I talking about major news sites that occasionally mention Bitcoins. I'd like to know where should one go if they want the latests ins and outs of all things Bitcoin related in a digestible form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are a list of blogs/sites I follow to keep up with bitcoin news:

[reddit/r/bitcoin](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/) - user aggregated bitcoin links/topics, usually anything notable will be posted here.

[Bitcoin Magazine](http://bitcoinmagazine.com/) - also available as an actual physical print magazine.

[Cryptocoin News](https://cryptocoinsnews.com/) - mentions altcoins, but Bitcoin is most prominent

[CoinDesk](http://www.coindesk.com/) - a relatively new entrant to the Bitcoin news space

[The Genesis Block](http://www.thegenesisblock.com/)

[The Monetary Future](http://themonetaryfuture.blogspot.com/) - not exclusively bitcoin related but often covers bitcoin or related topics. This blogger (Jon Matonis)  is now a [Forbes blogger](http://blogs.forbes.com/jonmatonis/) and the content will typically appear on the [Forbes](http://blogs.forbes.com/jonmatonis/) site first.

[Coding in my sleep](http://codinginmysleep.com/) - a personal blog  but more and more bitcoin related topics recently.

[The Bitcoin Trader](http://www.thebitcointrader.com/) - excellent blog on bitcoin related topics. (less active recently (end 2012))

[Bitcoin Money](http://www.bitcoinmoney.com/) - another bitcoin blog.

[Bitcoin Miner](http://www.bitcoinminer.com/) - bitcoin mining focused blog.

[Bitcoin Watch](http://bitcoinwatch.com/) - has a collection of links to the latest news along with exchange stats etc.

[stuffexists.com](http://stuffexists.com/) - collection of lots of useful links.

[Bitcoin Media](http://bitcoinmedia.com/) - blog with articles mainly by Amir Taaki (genjix) (a Bitcoin developer)

[blockchained.com](http://blockchained.com/) - has a Top 16 Hot Topics from Bitcointalk.org (seems to use an algorithm to rank the most active current topics) as well as charts an some news links (was [bitcoinx.com](http://www.bitcoinx.com/charts/) but that currently only has charts)

[Bitcoin on Quora](http://www.quora.com/bitcoinboard)

[Bitcoin on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=bitcoin)

The press [sub-forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=77.0) of bitcointalk.org is usually kept up to date with any press on bitcoin

Comment: might add http://coinie.com/  and  http://bitcoin.alltop.com/  to that

Comment: I wasn't aware of the coinie.com site - thanks for that.

Comment: For the last six months, I have been co-maintaining the [BitcoinBoard](http://www.quora.com/bitcoinboard) on Quora. This board is for sharing news and ideas related to the bitcoin economy, such as trading, mining, transactions and companies. Please feel free to post items that include analysis and critique rather than just an announcement of a new company or service.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, besides the forums and SE, I'm following the [sub-Reddit](http://reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to gather the most serious, interesting and long lasting ones on http://bitcoin.gw.gd/

There are many sections, but the most important one is http://bitcoin.gw.gd/-Bitcoin-News-  , currently including the rss feeds from more than 40 websites including betabeat, wired, CNN and many others.

This list is maintained and new websites are regularly added to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.thebitcoinreview.com/](http://www.thebitcoinreview.com/index.php)

look at the Commerce and community setction for a complete list of these types of sites.

once you found the site you like best consider posting a review on [TheBitcoinReview.com](http://www.thebitcoinreview.com/index.php) to help us weed out the good sites from the bad

Comment: You should consider proofreading your answer before posting it. It would be also nice if you provided a link straight to the section you are referring to.