# Is there a central repository of bitcoin conferences?

Tags: development, websites

I currently use CoinDesk to remain abreast on events and conferences. Any other websites I should utilize?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most respectable Bitcoin news websites?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/what-are-the-most-respectable-bitcoin-news-websites)

Comment: @Geremia: This question is about Bitcoin conferences, I don't understand why you suggest a question about news websites as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you are looking for. If you want to publish academic research, the most well known conferences are:

- Conference on Computer and Communications Security (CCS)
- USENIX Security (USENIX Security)
- IEEE Symposium on Security and Privacy (S&P)
- Financial Cryptography and Data Security (FC)
- Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT)
- Network and Distributed System Security Symposium (NDSS)

Note that if you are not academically interested, those might not be for you.

Answer (score 0):

THey haven't been as prolific as in the past but here's a few:

https://bitcoin.org/en/events
http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-events/

As you've said coindesk is usually up to date.